# Jest cannot compile absolute imports in a React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, jestjs

I'm using absolute imports in my project, but when I try to import a module, Jest is unable to compile it. I have tried adding the folder paths to the **moduleNameMapper** object, but this is not working. How do I get Jest to compile these imports without error?

[image]

**Jest Config**

```
module.exports = {
    rootDir: 'src',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.s?css$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '^app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1'
    },
    transform: {
        '\\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|jpg|png)$': '../jest/fileTransformer.js',
        '\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/(?!lodash-es).+\\.js$'
    ],
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '**/*.{js,jsx}'
    ],
    coverageDirectory: '../coverage'
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    },
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ]
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./src/types",
    "./src/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

**weboack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
            extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'],
            alias: {
                '@': path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            }
        },
```

**App.jsx**

```
import { applyDefaultsToOptions } from '@/modules/charts';
import './App.scss';

const App = () => {
    const initOptions = applyDefaultsToOptions();

    return <Chart initOptions ={initOptions }/>;
};

export default App;
```

**App.test.jsx**

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders the landing page', () => {
    render(<App />);
});
```

[image]